# Number of updates pending on Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I am running BGInfo on my servers and putting the results into a single database. One thing that I want to record is the number of updates the server believes that it needs. I can do this on Windows 2003, Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2 by looking at the registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UAS\UpdateCount

However on Windows 2012R2 (AKA Windows 6.2) it always returns 0 even when there updates outstanding.

Does anyone know where registry key is hiding that will give the true number?

FYI I have also looked at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UpdatesAvailableForDownloadLogon
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UpdatesAvailableForInstallLogon
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UpdatesAvailableWithUiLogon
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UpdatesAvailableWithUiOrEulaLogon

And they are all 0 as well.

Comment: FYI 2012 is 6.2 2012 R2 is 6.3